# Pattern matching with PDF, Distributed and multivariate distributions

Tags: pattern-matching, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have defined a function to compute the Shannon entropy of a probability distribution:

```
ent[p_] := Expectation[-Log[PDF[p, x]], x \[Distributed] p]
```

This works fine for univarite distributions:

```
nd = NormalDistribution[]
ent[nd]

Out[9]= 1/2 (1 + Log[2 \[Pi]])
```

I would have expected `ent` to work with multivariate distributions as well,
since `x \[Distributed] p` in `ent` should cause `x` to be bound to vectors of the appropriate length to make `PDF[p, x]` work, but I get

```
nd2 = ProductDistribution[nd, nd]
ent[nd2] // FullSimplify

Out[10]= Expectation[-Log[
   PDF[ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
     NormalDistribution[0, 1]], x]], 
 x \[Distributed] 
  ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   NormalDistribution[0, 1]]]
```

I can write a specific function for each arity:

```
ent2[p_] := Expectation[-Log[PDF[p, {x, y}]], {x, y} \[Distributed] p]
ent2[nd2]

Out[11]= 1 + Log[2 \[Pi]]
```

Is there a way to write ent to be generic wrt to the dimention of the distribution?
I would also like to better understand why `ent` does not work for multivariate distributions as is. The definition seems mathematically correct for any dimention.

Comment: You'll need to parse out the distribution, arriving at the number of vars needed for say the PDF, then generate these (say using `With` and `Unique`), and inject these. Your expectation this will happen "automagically" with `x~p` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment (this is *not* a fleshed out answer, just an example ):

```
entX[p_] := With[{vars = Unique[] & /@ Range@Length@p},
  Expectation[-Log[PDF[p, vars]], vars \[Distributed] p]]

entX[nd2]

(* 1+Log[2 π] *)
```

Note, you'll want to use more sophistacated means to detrmine needed number, `Length` works here for your example, and is probably OK for some generic combination distributions, but will fail in many cases (e.g., if you feed it just `nd` from your example, it sees the default values for `NormalDistribution` and poops two variables instead of one.)

Comment: Combined with the pointer to to Statistics`Library`DistributionDimensionality give in the answer  to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46309/determining-the-dimension-of-a-probability-distribution I think this provides a complete solution. I would still like to better understand why the original `ent` does not work though

Comment: @DanielMahler: Ooh! Thanks for that link! Even though undocumented, that's going to be useful.