# Determining the dimension of a probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Functions like `Mean` and `RandomVariate` clearly infer the dimension of the distribution passed to them. One can also usually determine the dimension of a distribution by calling one of these functions, but this is suboptimal. `RandomVariate` does not work if some of the parameters of the distribution are symbolic and long tailed distributions may not have a well defined mean. Even when this method works it is overkill. Presumably there is some lower level function that just determines the dimension that `Mean` and `RandomVariate` themselves use to determine the dimesion but I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `DistributionDomain` to find the domain of a distribution, which will also tell you the dimension.

I do not know where this is documented, but it [does appear](http://reference.wolfram.com/documentation-search.html?query=DistributionDomain&collection=reference&lang=en) in some examples in the documentation.

Usage examples:

```
DistributionDomain[NormalDistribution[]]
(* Interval[{-∞, ∞}] *)

DistributionDomain[ParetoDistribution[xmin, alpha]]
(* Interval[{xmin, ∞}] *)

DistributionDomain[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]
(* {Interval[{-∞, ∞}], Interval[{-∞, ∞}]} *)

data = RandomReal[1, 10]
(* {0.60996, 0.615194, 0.106301, 0.543126, 0.812796, 0.711574, 0.814802, 0.839422, 0.0528327, 0.40623} *)

DistributionDomain[EmpiricalDistribution[data]]
(* {0.0528327, 0.106301, 0.40623, 0.543126, 0.60996, 0.615194, 0.711574, 0.812796, 0.814802, 0.839422} *)

% == Sort[data]
(* True *)

DistributionDomain[ZipfDistribution[rho]]
(* Range[1, ∞] *)

DistributionDomain[ZipfDistribution[10, rho]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

Notice that a simple `Length@DistributionDomain[...]` isn't sufficient to determine the dimension.  There are helper functions to determine if a distribution (or its domain) are univariate.

- `` Statistics`Library`UnivariateDomainSpecificationQ `` can be applied to a domain specification
- `` Statistics`Library`UnivariateDistributionQ `` can be applied to a distribution and is based on the function above.

There is also `` Statistics`Library`Dump`HeldDistributionDomain `` which prevents `Range` from expanding in the domain of some discrete distributions, for example:

```
Statistics`Library`Dump`HeldDistributionDomain[ZipfDistribution[10, rho]]
(* Hold[Range][1, 10] *)
```

Looking at its definition it simple uses `Block` to temporarily prevent `Range` from evaluating, which you can do manually yourself to reduce the reliance on private internal functions that might not even be loaded in a fresh kernel (until something else triggers loading them).

---

As Andy Ross mentioned in the comments, `` Statistics`Library`DistributionDimensionality `` will directly return the dimensionality of the domain.

---

**Warning:** As with all undocumented functions that are not in the `` System` `` context there's no guarantee of reliability or that they'll work in future versions.

Comment: I've never used this function before, I found it using some spelunking when I saw your question.

Comment: There is also ``Statistics`Library`DistributionDimensionality`` but I make no promises that it is robust.

Comment: @Andy I think you're in a much better position to answer this ... Is `DistributionDomain` robust?  It's not documented but it is in the System context.

Comment: Looks like @AndyRoss's `DistributionDimensionality` handles the corner cases that break `DistributionDomain` as @Szabolcs pointed out in the main answer

Comment: Together with Andy's comment this answers my question. I guess if @AndyRoss had written a separate answer I would have accepted that since `DistributionDimensionality` is really what I had in mind, assuming it is robust. Gotta love undocumented functions in closed software ;)

Comment: @AndyRoss & @Szabolcs How did you find these functions in the first place. How can I search/list all the functions in Statistics`Library`.

Comment: @DanielMahler Evaluate ``?Statistics`Library`*``.  Keep in mind that anything that's not documented and not in ``System` `` might go away/change in the next version, might crash your kernel, or might give you a wrong result.  *Yes, these things do actually happen.*  I found `DistributionDomain` by making a good guess and searching for `?*Domain*`.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs! I did not realize that `?` supports pattern matching. That is very useful.

Comment: @DanielMahler `?something*` will search in all contexts that are in `$ContextPath` and ``?*`something*`` will search in *all* contexts.  The latter tends to return a lot of internal stuff that's not useful, so there's more to wade through.  The warnings I gave you about undocumented/internal stuff are not meant to deter you, I sometimes use these too.  But the problems can and do happen (I've been bitten several times.)

Comment: ThanksAgain @Szabolcs. I appreciate your warnings about  Statistics`Library`, but it looks like I will have to live in the land of undocumented functions if I actually want to get useful things done with Mathematica, as by the sounds of it, do you. I have absolutely no objections to more functions getting tested, documented and made official though :)

Comment: Also @Szabolcz how did you figure oout what paarameters it takes once you found it>

Comment: @Daniel Well, for `DistributionDomain` the first guess is pretty obvious and it worked.  But you can always try a bit of [spelunking](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/12) to find interesting stuff ;-)  Use the (newer) code from GitHub.

Comment: @Szabolcs I believe `DistributionDomain` is fairly robust but it may be that the representation of domains may change in the future. Some things are pretty wonky, like held ranges to infinity, and probably need different symbols to represent them.