# Loading Statistics`Library`

Tags: packages, probability-or-statistics

I need to use a number of functions from the`` Statistics`Library` `` namespace. Since that is a bit of a mouthful I would like to import it, but I get errors:

```
In[42]:= Needs["Statistics`Library`"]

During evaluation of In[42]:= Get::noopen: Cannot open Statistics`Library`. >>

During evaluation of In[42]:= Needs::nocont: Context Statistics`Library` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>

Out[42]= $Failed

In[43]:= << Statistics`Library`

During evaluation of In[43]:= Get::noopen: Cannot open Statistics`Library`. >>

Out[43]= $Failed
```

I can use individual functions from the namespace

```
In[44]:= Statistics`Library`DistributionDimensionality[
```

NormalDistribution[]]

```
Out[44]= 1
```

so the problem is not in the name.

What is the problem then? What is the correct way to do the import?

Comment: I don't think you can "load" these in that way (could be wrong though), why not just set up some aliases, e.g. ``dd = Statistics`Library`DistributionDimensionality`, then `dd[NormalDistribution[]]` does it...

Comment: It's a good idea to give some context for your question and link back to [the original thread that prompted this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46310/12).  ``Statistics`Library` `` is not a package, so it can't be loaded.  (Loading is triggered by the use of some other stats functions.)  It is a context (namespace) containing functions meant for internal use: there's no documentation, no guarantee these functions will work properly or that they won't crash your kernel or cause memory leaks, and they're likely to change in future versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`` Statistics`Library` `` does not correspond directly to a package path, so it cannot be loaded with `Get` or `Needs`. Rather, this contents of this context come from

```
FileNameJoin[{
 $InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel", "SystemResources", $OperatingSystem,
 "Statistics", "Library.mx"
}]
```

which is loaded automatically at startup. Loading this file populates the context, but does not add anything to the context path.

It is straightforward to change the context path, however:

```
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Statistics`Library`"]
```

Now:

```
DistributionDimensionality@NormalDistribution[] (* -> 1 *)
```