# Domain of ProbabilityDistributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to do some symbolic statistics.
Is there a way to get the Domain of a distribution?
Like this

```
Domain[UniformDistribution[]]
>> 0<=x<=1

Domain[BinomialDistribution[n,p]]
>> 0 <= x <= n && x \[elem] Integers
```

I assume that some kind of function like this is used by `Expectation` and other descriptive statiscal function.

Comment: Use `DistributionDomain[...]`. It's lacking documentation apparently but it does what you need. The proper term for this is the 'support'  of a random variable. See this answer here too: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46310/72682

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DistributionDomain[]`. It's lacking documentation apparently:

```
DistributionDomain[TriangularDistribution[{a, b}]]
(* Interval[{a, b}] *)

DistributionDomain[NormalDistribution[m, s]]
(* Interval[{-∞, ∞}] *)

DistributionDomain[ParetoDistribution[a, 1]]
(* Interval[{a, ∞}] *)

DistributionDomain[CategoricalDistribution[{"cow", "chicken", "potato"}]]
(* {"cow", "chicken", "potato"} *)
```