# Get All Discrete Univariate Distributions with Symbolic Parameters

Tags: probability-or-statistics, symbolic, built-in-symbols, system

I am trying to get all Discrete Univariate Distributions with symbolic arguments from any place in Wolfram Language system. For example this guide:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DiscreteUnivariateDistributions.html

or maybe some information in `WolframLanguageData`. The final form of output should be a list

```
{ZipfDistribution[ρ], ZipfDistribution[n,ρ], LogSeriesDistribution[θ], ...etc.}
```

giving complete set of all Discrete Univariate Distributions. Perhaps this might be useful, but this mixes in continuous distributions which I do not need and it also does not give symbolic arguments:

```
EntityList[
    EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol",
    {"FunctionalityAreas"->EqualTo[{"StatisticalDistributionSymbols"}]}]]
```

This might be useful too:

```
Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "ZipfDistribution"]["PlaintextUsage"]
Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "ZipfDistribution"]["TypesetUsage"]
```

> - ZipfDistribution[ρ] represents a zeta distribution with parameter ρ.
> - ZipfDistribution[n, ρ] represents a Zipf distribution with range n.

Comment: Probably `DistributionDomain` will help.  `DistributionDomain[ZipfDistribution[\[Rho]]]` results in `1 ;; \[Infinity]` and `DistributionDomain[NormalDistribution[]]` results in `Interval[{-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`.

Comment: Related:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46309/determining-the-dimension-of-a-probability-distribution/46310#46310.  A list of the library functions (`?`Statistics`Library`*`)  finds a function named `DiscreteDistributionQ` but I can't get it to work.  (Nor can I get the previous text to format properly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating a list of the discrete univariate distributions in *Mathematica* is difficult for me not only because after all these years I'm still not great at *Mathematica* programming but because there are "issues" with defining what constitutes a discrete univariate distribution.

For example, there is the `CompoundPoisson` distribution which can be discrete or continuous depending on whether the user-selected "jump size" distribution is discrete or continuous.  There are also an additional assortment of "helper" distribution functions which can work on discrete or continuous distributions with the result being a distribution but not necessarily having a recognized name: `CensoredDistribution`,  `MarginalDistribution`, `MixtureDistribution`, `OrderDistribution`, `ParameterMixtureDistribution`, `SplicedDistribution`, and `TransformedDistribution`.

Fortunately, there is a function that will return `True` or `False` for if a distribution is (always) a discrete univariate distribution.  For example:

```
Statistics`Library`DiscreteUnivariateDistributionQ[PoissonDistribution[μ]]
(* True *)
```

(See [Determining the dimension of a probability distribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46309/determining-the-dimension-of-a-probability-distribution/46310#46310) for more details.)

Using the listing code provided by @VitaliyKaurov the following will produce a list of the (always) discrete univariate distributions:

```
(* Get the list of StatisticalDistributionSymbols *)
sds = EntityList[
   EntityClass[
    "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityAreas" -> 
      EqualTo[{"StatisticalDistributionSymbols"}]}]];

(* Now extract the name of the distributions along with some "default"/standard parameter symbols
   which are essential *)
distributions = EntityValue[#, "PlaintextUsage"] & /@ sds;
distributions = StringTake[#, StringPosition[#, "]"][[1, 1]]] & /@ distributions

(* Now the list of discrete univariate distributions *)
(discreteUnivariateDistributions = Select[distributions,
  Statistics`Library`DiscreteUnivariateDistributionQ[ToExpression[#]] &])//Tableform
```

[image: List of always discrete univariate distributions]

Comment: Neat thank you for relentless effort :-)