# Visualizing density given by its Stieltjes transformation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, visualization

How can I use Mathematica to get $f(y)$, the PDF of a random variable given its Stieltjes transform $g(s)$?

$$g(s)=E\left[1/(s-X)\right]$$

I need to visualize probability density of a random variable  $X\in(0,1]$ with the following Stieltjes transform:

```
stieltjes=(Sqrt[2] (\[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[s]/Sqrt[2]]))/(2 Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[2] s ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]])
```

Expecting this PDF to look similar to $\operatorname{Beta}\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$

---

Trying on some simpler distributions first:

Using Beta$(1/2,1)$ we have the following pdf $f(y)$ and $g(s)$

```
pdf = 1/2 y^(-1/2); (* BetaDistribution[1/2,1] *)
stieltjes = Integrate[pdf 1/(s - y), {y, 0, 1}]
```

$$f(y)=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}}{2} \leftrightarrow g(s)=\frac{\coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s}\right)}{\sqrt{s}}$$

Also, using $1/x^2$ where $x$ is Zipf distributed as in the earlier [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286827/217) we have the following

```
distY = TransformedDistribution[1/z^2, 
   z \[Distributed] ZipfDistribution[1]];
Expectation[1/(s - i), i \[Distributed] distY]
```

$$f(y)=\left(1, \frac{6}{\pi ^2}\right),\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{2 \pi ^2}\right), \left(\frac{1}{9} , \frac{2}{3 \pi ^2}\right),\ldots  \leftrightarrow g(s)=-\frac{3 \left(\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{s}}\right)-\sqrt{s}\right)}{\pi ^2 \sqrt{s}}$$

You can get Stieltjes Transforms by chaining two Laplace transforms together as seen below. Wondering if there's a way to use this to get symbolic or numeric inversion working for examples above.

```
dist = BetaDistribution[1/2, 1];
mgf = MomentGeneratingFunction[BetaDistribution[1/2, 1], t];
doubleLaplace = LaplaceTransform[mgf, t, s] // FullSimplify;
stieltjes = Expectation[1/(s - y), y \[Distributed] dist];
doubleLaplace == stieltjes (*True if s>1*)
```

(note you often need Feynman trick to do inverse Laplace transforms in Mathematica, documented [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/laplace-transform-tricks.nb))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the formula at [Wiki Stieltjes Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation), we should be able to get the density as

$${\displaystyle \rho (x)=\lim _{\varepsilon \to 0^{+}}{\frac {S_{\rho }(x-i\varepsilon )-S_{\rho }(x+i\varepsilon )}{2i\pi }}.}$$

where $S_\rho$ is equivalent to your $g$.  I have not been successful at taking that limit with your `stieltjes` (as I keep getting 0 as the limit) but using very small values of $\epsilon$ I get the following approximation:

```
g[s_] := (Sqrt[2] (π - 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[s]/Sqrt[2]]))/(2 Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[2] s ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]])

f[x_, ϵ_] := (g[x - I ϵ] - g[x + I ϵ])/(2 π I) // N // Chop

Plot[f[x, 1/1000000], {x, -3, 1}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image: Estimate of probability density function]

But that doesn't look like your expected beta distribution with parameters 1/2 and 1.

**Update:**

By setting $x$ to rational values, using `Limit` worked and a pattern became apparent.  The pdf is given by

```
pdf[x_] := Piecewise[{{(4 Sqrt[2])/(Sqrt[-x] (8 - π^2 x + 
       4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x] ArcTan[(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x])/(-2 + x)] + 
       x ArcTan[(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x])/(-2 + x)]^2)), -2 < x < 0}}, 0]
```

$$\frac{4 \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{-x} \left(-\pi ^2 x+x \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x}}{x-2}\right)^2+4 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x}}{x-2}\right)+8\right)}$$

Comment: Interesting!.... actually that looks close to what I expected, my expression was obtained using two Laplace transforms instead of MFG followed by Laplace, so that may explain the negative sign

Comment: Does that formula work for the regular beta distribution? (Away from mathematica right now)

Comment: Yes but I've only got it to work for rational values of $x$:  `stieltjes[s_] := ArcCoth[Sqrt[s]]/Sqrt[s]; Limit[(stieltjes[x - I \[Epsilon]] - 
stieltjes[x + I \[Epsilon]])/(2 \[Pi] I) /. x -> 7/8, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` gives the same result as `PDF[BetaDistribution[1/2, 1], 7/8]`.

Comment: Thanks for the update...this expression is also the one I hit a dead end trying to compute the inverse Laplace transform of, being able to get the explicit expression for inverse Stieltjes is promising

Comment: I confirmed that this transformation is correct, limit + rational values seems like a useful trick to know! (background [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286939/approximating-a-function-for-which-both-laplace-and-inverse-laplace-transforms-a))