# Computing inverse discrete Stieltjes transform?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a way to invert the Stieltjes transform of a discrete distribution in Mathematica? IE, given $g(u)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i) \frac{1}{u-f(i)}$, obtain $f(i)$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f = x^-2;
g = Sum[ f/(u - f), {x, 1, \[Infinity]}] (* (Sqrt[u] - \[Pi] Cot[\[Pi]/Sqrt[u]])/(2 Sqrt[u]) *)
```

For a continuous distribution, the recipe is given by JimB [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286916/217)

**Edit**

it seems possible to invert by following the recipe [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4726262/998) if there were a way to get all the singularities of $g$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f = x^-2;
g = Sum[f/(u - f), {x, 
   1, \[Infinity]}] (*(Sqrt[u]-\[Pi] Cot[\[Pi]/Sqrt[u]])/(2 Sqrt[u])*)
singularities = Table[1/i^2, {i, 1, 10}];
Print["f=", f];
Print["g=", g];
Table[Residue[g, {u, u0}]/u0, {u0, singularities}]
```

Comment: (1) You have infinitely many poles so they go to (complex) infinity and you won't be able to get all of them numerically. (2) As noted, you can get your values `f(i)` if you know the singularities of g`. But that's kind of obvious already, because the singularities are exactly the `f(i)`. (3) You can isolate poles by rectangular subdivision, and use that to find all in some given rectangular range.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I was curious if one could go from $\frac{\sqrt{u}-\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{u}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{u}}$ to $x^{-2}$ using symbolic manipulation, analogous how JimB could do it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286914/visualizing-density-given-by-its-stieltjes-transformation) in the continuous case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (at best) a partial answer. A bit of calculus shows you can substitute `x` for `Sqrt[u]` to get `x - Pi*Cot[Pi/x]` (the change of variable differential conveniently cancels the `2*x` denominator). The poles are clearly at reciprocals of integers. We will compute some residues.

```
ee = 2*x*(x - Pi*Cot[Pi/x])/(2*x);
etab = Chop[Table[
   rep = 1/j + .001*Exp[2*Pi*I*t];
   ff = ee*D[rep, t] /. x -> rep;
   1/(2*Pi*I)*NIntegrate[ff, {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 12],
   {j, 1, 20}]]

(* Out[89]= {1., 0.25, 0.111111, 0.0625, 0.04, 0.0277778, 0.0204082, \
0.015625, 0.0123457, 0.01, 0.00826446, 0.00694444, 0.00591716, \
0.00510204, 0.00444444, 0.00390625, 0.00346021, 0.00308642, \
0.00277008, 0.0025} *)
```

Now rationalize them to see what we have.

```
Rationalize[etab]

(* Out[92]= {1, 1/4, 1/9, 1/16, 1/25, 1/36, 1/49, 1/64, 1/81, 1/100, \
1/121, 1/144, 1/169, 1/196, 1/225, 1/256, 1/289, 1/324, 1/361, 1/400} *)
```

This does give the values for `x^(-2)`. Not sure it was quite what you want but maybe it will give some ideas?

Comment: I'm curious why you use `NIntegrate` instead of built-in `Residue` function

Comment: Didn’t think of it and was short on time. It occurs to me that it’s easier just to note that the poles of you function of u occur at reciprocals of squared integers. But it’s nice to see the CIF working as expected.